# Picasso Images are loading slow in android, why?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

The images from the Picasso libery are loading in the emulater after a few clicks and very slow. Why are they loading so slow? And what do I have to do to make them load faster. I tried it with png files and jpg.

Java code

```
 private int a;
 ImageView ivImageFromUrl;


 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ivImageFromUrl=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.iv_image_from_url);

}

 public void buttonOnClick(View v)  {
    // do something when the button is clicked
    Button button = (Button) v;

    a = (byte) (Math.random() * 5);

    switch (a) {
        case 1:
            Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load("http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/crountch/one-piece-jolly-roger/72/Luffys-flag-2-icon.png").into(ivImageFromUrl);
          break;
        case 2:
            Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load("http://i40.tinypic.com/2i8xait.jpg").into(ivImageFromUrl);
            break;
        case 3:
            Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load("http://i41.tinypic.com/2i8xahh.jpg").into(ivImageFromUrl);
            break;
        case 4:
            Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load("http://i42.tinypic.com/2i8xahk.jpg").into(ivImageFromUrl);
            break;
        case 5:
            Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load("http://i40.tinypic.com/2i8xagp.jpg").into(ivImageFromUrl);
            break;
    }
}
}
```

XML

```
  <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello World!"
    android:id="@+id/textView2" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Image text"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="82dp" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Image"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:onClick="buttonOnClick"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="41dp" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/iv_image_from_url"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_marginBottom="106dp" />
```

Comment: Do you have a fast internet connection?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If your images are too large, then it may take some time.

If you need to show profile picture, whose size in your layout is 350x350, then why load full image. Re-size the image as per your requirement.

```
Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load(filePath).resize(400,400).centerCrop().into(imageView);
```

Comment: Should the resize parameters here be (400, 400) or should they be (350, 350) as per your example?

Comment: @user1898712 It could be any size as per your requirement.

Comment: @user1898712 if resize into 350X350 the image will be of very low quality its better to use 400X400.