# How to Pass URL Image to another activity Android studio

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-recyclerview

Im trying to send URL Image to another activity at my App. It was successfully added to the circleview for Recycler List, but when i implemented it to intent, it wasn't work.

I tried every tutorial at youtube with no success.

**Intent at Main Activity :**

```
private void showSelectedTeam(Team team) {
        Intent moveIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, HalamanDeskripsi.class);
        moveIntent.putExtra("restid",team.getPhoto());
        moveIntent.putExtra(HalamanDeskripsi.EXTRA_NAME,team.getName());
        moveIntent.putExtra(HalamanDeskripsi.EXTRA_DESC,team.getFrom());
        startActivity(moveIntent);
        }
}
```

**Received at Detailed Activity :**

```
ImageView iv = findViewById(R.id.gambar_desc);

        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        int res = bundle.getInt("restid");
        iv.setImageResource(res);

        TextView tvDataReceived = findViewById(R.id.tv_hd_nama);
        TextView tvDataReceived2 = findViewById(R.id.tv_hd_desc);

        String name = getIntent().getStringExtra(EXTRA_NAME);
        tvDataReceived.setText(name);

        String desc = getIntent().getStringExtra(EXTRA_DESC);
        tvDataReceived2.setText(desc);
    }
```

**Team Class :**

```
public class Team {
    private String name;
    private String Description;
    private String photo;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getFrom() {
        return Description;
    }

    public void setFrom(String from) {
        this.Description = from;
    }

    public String getPhoto() {
        return photo;
    }

    public void setPhoto(String photo) {
        this.photo = photo;
    }
}
```

**Data from Array class :**

```
public class DataTeam {
public static String[][] data = new String[][]{
        {"Arsenal",
                "Arsenal Football Club (dikenal pula sebagai Arsenal atau The Gunners) adalah klub sepak bola profesional Inggris yang berbasis di daerah Holloway, London. didirikan pada 1886 dengan nama Dial Square. ",
                "https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1888/7339/files/Arsenal_17_grande.jpg?v=1498047935"},
        {"Aston Villa",
                "Jenderal TNI Anumerta Ahmad Yani (juga dieja Achmad Yani; lahir di Purworejo, Jawa Tengah, 19 Juni 1922 – meninggal di Lubang Buaya, Jakarta, 1 Oktober 1965 pada umur 43 tahun) adalah .",
                "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/f/f9/Aston_Villa_FC_crest_%282016%29.svg/1200px-Aston_Villa_FC_crest_%282016%29.svg.png"},
        {"Bournemouth",
                "Sutomo (lahir di Surabaya, Jawa Timur, 3 Oktober 1920 – meninggal di Padang Arafah, Arab Saudi, 7 Oktober 1981 pada umur 61 tahun)",
                "https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1888/7339/files/AFCB_08_grande.jpg?v=1498048525"}

};
public static ArrayList<Team> getListData(){
    ArrayList<Team> list = new ArrayList<>();
    for (String[] aData : data) {
        Team team = new Team();
        team.setName(aData[0]);
        team.setFrom(aData[1]);
        team.setPhoto(aData[2]);
        list.add(team);
    }
    return list;
}
```

When i run this at my phone, the detailed text is sended successfully, but the picture is not loaded. please help me

Comment: you are passing wrong key.Instead of resid it should be restid.

Comment: oh my bad, but still doesnt work after i fixed it.

Comment: What does `team.getPhoto()` return, exactly? You refer to a URL in your description, but you're trying to use that value as a resource ID.

Comment: Team is the java class, where my getter and setter is constructed.
getPhoto is the array of image URL.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to post the `Team` class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: As per updated information
It seems you are trying to load image from an url, It is easier to use Picasso or Glide library

Update gradle

```
 implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
```

Get image and load

```
String res = bundle.getString("resid");
Picasso.get().load(res).into(iv);
```

Comment: " setImageResource(int) in ImageView cannot be applied to ( java.lang.String ). there is this error command.

Comment: THANK YOU IT WORK! its taking 20-30 second, but it was loaded successfully! ill set this as the answer, and it could be fantastic if u can sugest me how to make it load faster.

Comment: If images are too large try resizing them. Refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37399131/picasso-images-are-loading-slow-in-android-why/37399564